# How to use two emulators at the same time in the same project in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator, smsmanager

I working in Android Studio and I need some help regarding the emulators.

I want to start two emulators so I can use them the same time to test my application.
Right now the problem is that when the second emulator loads everything just crashes.

How can I solve this?

Please help!

Answer (score 10):

You can run multiple emulators at the same time simply by running your app again. When the AVD manager pops up, instead of selecting your already running emulator, click 'Launch Emulator' and select another emulator to launch.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
This is exactly what im doing but the new emulator is ssooo slow..it also says HAX is not working when i launch the second emulator and everything just crashes..its not running seconde emulator in fast virt mode.

Comment: Im getting this in my console for emulator 2:
emulator: The memory needed by this VM exceeds the driver limit.
HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
This runs veeeeeerrrrrry slooooowwww

And for emulator 1:
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode

Comment: You may need to adjust how much memory you have allocated for HAX and make sure that both emulators are using only the available memory. I can't use HAX right now because of a BIOS issue. Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: Thank you!
I fixed it.
Han to reinstall HAXM and increase the memory option!

Comment: Can I use the same local server for both emulators?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, if you already downloaded in the AVD a system image, just create another emulator with that same image, not need to download another one, change the name of that device and start one app in one emulator and the other in the other one